# Setting passed ofstream to class wide variable

Tags: c++, file-io

I have a constructor for my class: `class(ofstream & o)`. I want to set my class variable `ofstream out`. The problem is I can't use `out = o` without getting an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you'd do is something like:

```
   class MyClass
   {
      ofstream& out;
      MyClass(ofstream& o) : out(o)
      {}
      ...
    };
```

This will work, and internally you can use `out` as usual.

In your question, you say `ofstream out`. You cannot "copy" file streams, so you cannot say `out = o` unless `out` is a reference.

Comment: The class variable isn't a reference from what I can see. It should work the same way, but it's a different problem if it isn't a reference.

Comment: @chris: The class variable is declared `ofstream&` which *is* a reference.

Comment: The question says `ofstream out`. The parameter is a reference. I'm thinking there's a missing & in the question, though.

Comment: Ah, I see. File streams are not copyable, so you cannot pass them by copy, just reference (or pointer), and maintain that reference inside the class. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Interesting, didn't know that.

Comment: Almost, but references can't be assigned. They need the member initialization. Without the initialization there, they'd have to be null or something, too, which doesn't work.